# Cannot implement a recursive generator in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, generator, ienumerable

Hello! I want to implement this recursive generator in C# and I don't understand why it doesn't return anything. It is a depth-first search algorithm which provides all the possible paths between 2 points.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConvertDfsFromPython
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<string> a = new List<string> ();
            List<string> b = new List<string> ();
            List<string> e = new List<string> ();
            List<string> f = new List<string> ();
            List<string> c = new List<string> ();
            List<string> d = new List<string> ();
            List<string> g = new List<string> ();


            a.Add ("f");
            a.Add ("b");
            a.Add ("c");

            b.Add ("c");
            b.Add ("d");
            b.Add ("e");
            b.Add ("f");

            e.Add ("c");
            e.Add ("d");
            e.Add ("f");

            d.Add ("g");
            d.Add ("f");


            Dictionary<string, List<string>> graph = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> ();

            graph.Add ("a", a);
            graph.Add ("b", b);
            graph.Add ("c", c);
            graph.Add ("d", d);
            graph.Add ("e", e);
            graph.Add ("f", f);
            graph.Add ("g", g);



            MainClass myMainClass = new MainClass();

            IEnumerable<List<string>> getPath = myMainClass.dfsPath(graph, "a", "f");

            foreach (List<string> path in getPath) {
                foreach(string pathElement in path){
                    Console.WriteLine (pathElement);
                }
            }



        }

        public IEnumerable<List<string>> dfsPath(Dictionary<string, List<string>> graph, string root, string target, List<string> path = null){

            if(path == null){

                path = new List<string> ();
                path.Add (target);


            }

            if(root == target){
                yield return path;

                foreach (string element in path) {
                    Console.WriteLine (element);
                }
            }

            foreach(string vertex in graph[root]){

                if (!path.Contains(vertex)){

                    path.Add (vertex);

                    foreach(List<string> eachPath in dfsPath(graph, vertex, target, path )) {
                        yield return eachPath;

                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your first problem is that your root will never match the target, unless you pass the same values into the function. You are adding the target to the path, which prevents a recursive function call, resulting in the root and target to never match

Comment: Thank for the tip. It has to be path.Add(root) instead of path.Add(target). But even with this mistake fixed I still have other problems. It returns just one path instead of returning all the paths. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: you are returning the result as soon as you find a path. No further paths are evaluated. What you could do is to add `eachPath` to a new list instead of `yield return eachPath`. This will add all the paths to a list instead of returning as soon as it finds one. Then, do a yield return on the new list containing all the results.

Comment: it is still not working. It returns 1 list, when it should return 5.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your test data, but frankly, it doesn't look like you even need a recursive function. You can just find all the paths that start with your route and end with your target by looking at the first and last entry. If you want the paths that might not end at the target, but crosses it, you'd check the first for the root, and the remaining for the target. No recursion required.